# Is there any way to automatically manage preflight endpoints for each of the endpoint in serverless (AWS Lambda)

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, preflight

I'm working on AWS Lambda using serverless framework and I need to specify two methods in `functions.yml` for each of the API. For example, if I have to create an endpoint for getting books `http://basic-url.com/api/books/all`. I have to add two methods for it in `functions.yml` as follows.

```
get_books:
  handler: books/handler.get_books
  tags:
    Name: get-books
  events:
    - httpApi:
        method: GET
        path: /api/books/all

get_books_preflight:
  handler: default/handler.get_preflight
  tags:
    Name: get-preflight
  events:
    - httpApi:
        method: OPTIONS
        path: /api/books/all
```

I have to specify preflight for all of endpoints that I want to create in `functions.yml`. Is there any way to manage these preflight endpoints for each endpoint automatically?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a function for each preflight endpoint.

When a browser receives a non-simple HTTP request, the CORS protocol requires the browser to send a preflight request to the server and wait for approval (or a request for credentials) from the server before sending the actual request. The preflight request appears to your API as an HTTP request that:

- Includes an Origin header.
- Uses the OPTIONS method.
- Includes the following headers:

  - Access-Control-Request-Method
  - Access-Control-Request-Headers

To support CORS, therefore, a REST API resource needs to implement an OPTIONS method that can respond to the OPTIONS preflight request with at least the following response headers mandated by the Fetch standard:

- Access-Control-Allow-Methods
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin

With Serverless Framework you can do this in two easy steps:

1. Add the `cors: true` flag to each HTTP endpoint in your `serverless.yml`:

```
getBooks:
  handler: books/handler.getBooks
  tags:
    Name: get-books
  events:
    - http:
        path: /api/books/all
        method: GET
        cors: true
```

2. Add the following headers to your response:

```
module.exports.getBooks = (event, context, callback) => {

  // Do work to retrieve a Book
  const book = retrieveBook(event);

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      book: book
    }),
  };

  callback(null, response);
};
```

Eventually, if you use Javascript, take a look to [Middy](https://github.com/middyjs/middy) middleware engine for use with Lambda. It has a lot of nice middlewares and one is the [cors middleware](https://github.com/middyjs/middy/tree/master/packages/http-cors), which automatically adds CORS headers to your functions.

Comment: Thanks for the middy shout-out!

Comment: Hi @willFarrell, thank you for the amazing job you are doing ;)